# compile files from different directories with javac, referring a depending jar file?

Tags: java, command-line, javac

I have the following set up:

I have 4 packages:

- root/src/terminal - has some java files
- root/src/mail - has some java files
- root/src/data - has some java files
- root/src/main - has a single java file, Main.java

I also have the following files

- root/bin - a folder to store .class files
- root/mail.jar - a jar file which has important classes used in my code

Within the root, I would like to enter a terminal command which compiles root/src/main/Main.java and puts the class files in the root/bin location.

Can someone show me the command to do this? I'm on a Mac (running Leopard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the one liner:

```
cd /xyz/root
rm -rf bin/*
javac -d bin -classpath mail.jar -sourcepath src main/Main.java
```

Alternatively, you could use absolute directory names:

```
rm -rf /xyz/root/bin/*
javac -d /xyz/root/bin -classpath /xyz/root/mail.jar \
      -sourcepath /xyz/root/src /xyz/root/ main/Main.java
```

In reference to Ant you said *"I would rather keep it simple."*.

In fact in the long term it is simpler to create a simple Ant `build.xml` file.  The alternative is a bunch of non-portable scripts or batch file ... or lots of typing.

---

To run the application, assuming that you are still in the `/xyz/root` directory:

```
java -classpath bin:mail.jar main.Main
```

Or on Windows:

```
java -classpath bin;mail.jar main.Main
```

Or modify the above to use absolute pathnames in the classpath argument; e.g.

```
java -classpath /xyz/root/bin:/xyz/root/mail.jar main.Main
```

Comment: when I run the program using the java command, is there anything special I have to do. this worked quite well!!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your operating system?

What you should look into is using Apache Ant.  It is a build tool that once installed and configured can utilize a build.xml file in your root to compile class files to a folder as well as package a jar file.

http://ant.apache.org/

Comment: I would rather keep it simple. There is a simple one line solution which I am looking for. I'm not packaging a jar. I'm simply trying to link the jar so my java files know that the jar exists, because I import classes contained in that jar.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
javac -cp "/root/mail.jar;/root/src;" -d "/root/bin" Main.java
```

This is written hoping that you have package declarations in your classes from src folder like `package terminal;` and `package main;`.

See this: [Options in javac command](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)

Or use Apache Ant as suggested by maple_shaft.

---

From comment give by @maple_shaft:
In Unix, Linux operating systems the classpath separator is a colon instead of a semicolon.

Comment: I do have package declarations. And unfortunately, this still doesn't work. It says that the package terminal is not found (in my Main.java, I import terminal.Terminal.java)

Comment: also, since Main.java is in a package, I made it main/Main.java instead

Comment: @Harry, In Unix, Linux operating systems the classpath separator is a colon instead of a semicolon.  But other than that you are right.

Comment: @reising1: no need to use main/Main.java. It will start looking from src folder and will find all classes under that.

Comment: what about when I run the program using the java command? Do I have to do anything special. Because now I'm getting errors that classes aren't found once I actually run the program (the compiling works fine now)

Comment: @reising1: try: `java -cp "/root/mail.jar:/root/src:/root/bin" Main`. But it will require that all classes under src folder are compiled and class files for that reside in there.