# How to set up compiling and running Java in CMD

Tags: java, batch-file, compiler-construction, cmd, javac

I've looked in several places and seem to have difficulty in finding a good response.
I've managed to figure out how to compile and run Java code in CMD. However, is there a resource that explains how to create packages? JARs? How do I make it so when I compile my Java code it moves the class file into a different directory? i.e.
javac Work\src Main.java
java Work\bin Main

rather then dragging manually? Hopefully so I can turn all of this into a batch file?

Note, I'm using Windows 7 and don't care for the other commands to work it on Linux or Mac OS at the moment.

EDIT:
This is all so I can practice Java without an IDE which does everything for me, or in case I'm in a situation where I don't have one at my disposal.

### Thank you in advance!

Comment: highly recommend you with `maven`!

Comment: You should probably look into build management tools, such as [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/), [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) and [Gradle](http://www.gradleware.com/). Most modern [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s have these tools integrated as part of their environment.

Comment: If you want to get right back to basics, start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html).

Comment: See [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6044160/2587435) and see [**Packaging Programs in Jars**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has quite complete documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/index.html#basic) for the different command line tools. Ranked per tool and OS. This includes the [manuals to create jar files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) Good luck!